# kernel compilation failure [Ubuntu Lucid]

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, kernel, linux-kernel

I'm a newbie Linux/Ubuntu user. And I tried to compile a kernel as my Dell Studio 1555 laptop cannot be hibernated due to ATI open source graphic driver bug. So, I had to compile a kernel version 2.6.35-rc6 and apply a patch but before doing that version 2.6.35 came out, so I tried to compile the latter(2.6.35), but completely messed up the compilation process. Therefore, I completely crashed my system. I knew that when I rebooted and this kind of message showed up:

> **Kernel panic -not syncing: VFS: Unable**

So, what I would like to know is that, could this be resuced by booting from a Live CD and tried to get back to the previous Kernel version?

I have attached this [PATCH](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/474223/) I want to apply, so that people who could determine if the new version had fixed the bug or not.

Comment: compiling a kernel isn't something a linux newbie should be doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting with a live cd, then copying the working kernel over the damaged one. This is quick and dirty, but it seems like the easiest for a beginner.

Comment: what are the commands that I should use to achieve that? could you guide me more? thanks in advance.

Comment: When you boot, do you get the grub screen? do you have more than one kernel to choose from? if so, try the older ones. 
Otherwise follow this procedure, but you can use a ubuntu live cd instead of the knoppix cd - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=157250

Comment: Let us know if it does.